# Server CAL Licensing

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, iis, license, licensing

Almost need a lawyer just to figure this stuff out. Tried asking on Microsoft's support site through chat, but got thrown the typical "Please check this KB" bs.

I'm currently planning out an infrastructure. As it is right now, 90% of the servers will be Linux based, and user authentication will be handled within ApacheDS on a CentOS 7 virtual server. Part of the plan is going to require three Windows servers - one for hosting an IIS based website, and then two for hosting daeemons that external users (non-authenticated) can connect to and use. The IIS website will be authenticated, but through the LDAP server.

I will probably be able to support this across two rack units - two virtual server installs on one rack, and the other virtual server sitting alongside another Linux one on the other rack.

What, specifically, do I need in terms of licensing this? Do I need one Server 2016 license or two?

Also, in termsof CALs - in total, the size of the administration/IT team is projected to be 25 people within the next year or so. However, the maximum number of people that should have to concurrently be connected via either RDP or the IIS Manager to perform administration on any of the servers at one time is 5. It could be 5 on one server, or 3 on one 2 on another, etc.

Since my authentication is handled through ApacheDS and not through AD - how many CALs do I have to purchase, assuming I'm using User CALs (all connect at home, and I don't intend on limiting them to one device)? Just 5 for the maximum number of concurrent connections? Also, do I need some kind of a CAL or similar for the non-authenticated users that will be interacting with the daemon through a seperate program?

And are IIS Manager connections something that has to be included when purchasing CAL licensing?

I'm looking at Server 2016 Standard, by the way.

Comment: We are not lawyers.  If you have Microsoft Licensing questions contact Microsoft.  It doesn't matter, how authentication happens, a connection is a connection.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you need Windows Server Licenses for whatever number of Windows servers you are planning to provision.

In addition to the windows servers, you need RDS CAL's to RDP (full desktop or RAIL) into those server boxes either to administer the boxes or to run any applications.

You only need RDS CAL's for RDPing into those boxes, and don't require RDS CAL's to communicate with other programs.

Since you said, there will be 25 users who can remotely log-in to the servers and you don't want restrict the user limiting to one device,

The best option is to go for RDS Per-User CAL's and install them on the RDS licensing server.

Note: Since you are not using Active Directory, License Server can not update the issued licenses in AD and hence you will notice that the license are not being issued.

This is OK, as long as you comply with licensing terms and the number of licenses bought and the users connected are the same.

As a side note - Every windows server version allows two administrator sessions without requiring to have RDS calls (but the admin must connect with mstsc /admin)

I hope this answers  your question.

Comment: Reading this changes my interpretation.

When I say 25 people, I mean 25 people logging in to 1 of 5 accounts. Is it licensed per actual person/IP Address logging in to the server, or per actual user *account* allowed to login to the server? So, ie - if I had the accounts iisadmin, daemonAadmin, daemonBadmin, daemonCadmin and daemonDadmin... I'd only need 5 CALs for it?